# Are the tags used for types of termination fit for purporse

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

I noticed that some questions are using a tag layoff for circumstances where they are referring to some one being fired or being made redundant and not a layoff in the technical sense.

Formally a layoff has a specific meaning in hr terms (and in some places legal differences) i.e., you might lay off a night shift but those laid off have a right of return should work pickup

Might it be better to do away with laid off and just have fired and redundancy?

Comment: Nice catch! Do you have a suggestion of which tags to use for each? If you can come up with tags (and excerpts/descriptions), people can start re-tagging. I am more than happy to help out with creating the tags if needed, mind [edit]ing your question to include what you want to do about it? Thanks in advance!